# Proving an integral formula containing the Poisson kernel

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Specifically, the question is as follows:

> Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $f:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function such that both $\Re f$ and $\Im f$ are harmonic.
>
> (a) Show that
>   $$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(e^{it})P_r(\theta-t)dt$$
>   for all $re^{i\theta}$ in $\mathbb{D}$.
>
> (b) Show that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ if and only if
>   $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(e^{it})e^{int}dt=0$$
>   for all $n\geq1$.

I believe (a) is a direct consequence of Poisson's representation theorem for harmonic functions, stated as follows:

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk and $f:\partial\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then there exists a continuous function $u:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(z)=f(z)$ if $z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$, $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{D}$, and $u(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(\theta-t)f(e^{it})dt$ and $u$ is unique.

It seems to me that this can just be applied to the real and imaginary parts of the function $f$ from the question to derive the desired result, but maybe I'm making a careless mistake?

For (b), it's not obvious to me how part (a) assists in the solution. This is a homework question, so I am looking for assistance with understanding it, but not a full solution. Thanks.

Comment: can you please help me with part (b) of your question I have problem in this particular side  I have no idea on how I can prove that f is holomorphic if it satisfies $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{int}dt  =0 $.            Can you please help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poisson's representation formula here assumes only a function on the boundary. Also, one does not know the relationship between $u:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ from the theorem and $f:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ from the question (unless the proof of the theorem is constructive, then maybe you can deduce it), so you cannot use it like this here.

Hint for (a):

> Prove it first for holomorphic functions $g$, then use that $\Re f$ is the real part of some holomorphic function $g$. Same for $\Im f$.

Hint for (b):

> Letting $r\to 1$, we have for $t\neq 0$ that $P_r\to 0$. Now use the identity theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So for (a), using the representation formula, since $\mathbb{D}$ is simply connected, $u=\Re(g)$ where $g\in H(\mathbb{D})$, so $g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}f(e^{it})dt$ (where $f$ is from the representation formula). But this isn't quite the desired result. Should I not be trying to use the representation formula at all?

Comment: For a), I think all you need to do is show that the result holds for trigonometric polynomials, then you can use a density argument plus the DCT.

Comment: @Atsina To use my hint you don't need the representation formula, you only need to swap an integral and two series due to uniform convergence.